# Customizing mahout item based recommender for content based recommendations

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, information-retrieval, mahout-recommender

I'm trying to do recommendation for my eCommerce website(cloths/tee selling). There is no review or rating involved in the website. User can like the products and customize their preferences by adding keywords(ex: round neck, polo, casuals, jeans, party wear etc) to their profile preferences.

I'm trying to customize mahout item based recommender to include user's product preferences while calculating similarity. ItemSimilarity interface has methods only to compare between items. I need user's information/attributes for which we are calculating similarity so that i can add some boost if user preference matches products attributes. Basically i want to match users attributes and products attribute and do some computation to change similarity values.? Is there any article or tutorial explaining the same? It would be really helpful if somebody explain how this can be achieved by using mahout. Is there any other library which does content based recommendation? Many thanks in advance.